# Including Controller from Dependency Injection .net or other technique

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following situation : We are creating a wrapper of certain methods, example createTask, completeTask ,the first approach was expose also a webAPI to provide the functionalities for the frontEnd application. But this approach is no valid rigt now cause some cost and project limitation.

So are there any possibilities that my wrapper when the app use as dll reference or with dependency injection to also create automatically a controller or inject the endPoints inside de app that is using ?

I have in my library the ApiController in one class , but now i don't know how to move forward:

```
 [ApiController]
        [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
        public class ProcessController : Controller
        { 
      [HttpGet(Name ="xxxx")]
            public async Task<IList<xxx>> GetXXX(string 
             xxx)
            {
                return xxx
               
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the same Controller on multiple projects? You can use a Razor Class Library for this if you have a View or just a Class Library with the Web SDK to share the Controllers across applications. To inject the endpoints, you can check something like this https://github.com/JJConsulting/JJMasterData/blob/main/src/JJMasterData.Web/Extensions/WebApplicationExtensions.cs

Comment: Yes, I trying yo use the same controller on multiple applications ...